# Variables that DO NOT have the same length

Tags: r, variables

I am a newbie in R and I just know how to create the same codes.

Recently, I have had to delete some rows from my excel sheet because the data was very problematic, and if before I was analysing my data just fine with "**Shapiro test**" and "**Levene test**" to know if I would be able to do ANOVAs or not, now R says that "*response variable and grouping variable no longer have the same length*" and does not allow me to use the Levene test. I tried to use alternative tests such as "**Brown-Forsythe Test**" or "**Fligner test**" but I get the same error warnings.

Can anyone help please? :)

I would really appreciate it!!

"**Levene test**" does not seem to work if the variables do not have the same length, and other alternatives that GTP chat suggested lead to the same warnings, like "**Brown-Forsythe Test**" or "**Fligner test**".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you try to provide a reproducible example - that is, show us a little bit of data and the exact code you have tried so far?  More information here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/16730940

Comment: sorry for the late reply!!
My problem was somehow cleared. For next time I will add the codes! Thank you very much for answering!